# Android ImageView in RecyclerView has ghost

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

There is an ImageView in each ViewHolder for the RecyclerView(see the screenshot below). However, some of the images shown by the ImageViews have ghost on some devices.

[image: screen shot]

I have tried to add `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` attribute to the RecyclerView, but it didn't work.

**Edit 1**

The sources of these images are URLs loaded by Picasso. I found that this problem only happens after resizing.

**Edit 2**

The squared-red-border parts are the ghost.

[image]

Comment: What is the "ghost"? Can you annotate the images or otherwise describe what part of the image is undesirable?